# Removing Dropdown from screen when textarea not in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a chrome extension. When I click in a text field, a drop down opens and allows the user to interact. I want the drop drown to go away when a text area is not in focus.

So when the user clicks a text area the drop down opens, when the user clicks elsewhere it disappears.

I can't post the code for a variety of reasons but in javascript I create a divTag and an iFrame. I need to remove the divTag when the textarea is no longer in focus.

Comment: Do you want drop down menu in text area?

Comment: You can set the visibility of the box to `invisible` when the `onBlur` method fires.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').on('blur', function () {
    $('div').remove();
})
```